# Books on improving mathematical problem solving generally and in an exam setting

Tags: reference-request, big-list

looking at recommendations for books for people like me who are not mathematics naturals.

have been through polya's 'how to solve it' and noticed that i did not pick up those heuristics naturally through high school and 3 university courses on math.

want recommendations on books containing ideas on

i) problem solving heuristics
ii) memorization heuristics (if such a thing exists)
iii) taking math exams (problem solving speed etc)

in short, the kind of things naturals at math find easy and the non naturals would like some help with.

i wouldn't mind personal advice / technique on these dimensions either but not sure if the two different questions of books / personal advice can be rolled into one question here.

Comment: [Zeitz](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0471789011) might interest you...

Comment: I have converted the question to [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741), as it's asking for a list of references and there is no single right answer.

Answer (score 1):

A few books that I found interesting, perhaps you will too.

1) [How to develop a Super Power Memory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0811901815)

2) [Mathematical Morsels](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883853035)

3) [More Mathematical Morsels](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883853140)

4) [AOPS 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0977304566)

5) [AOPS 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1885875037)

Comment: Only the first link works for me...

Comment: @Byron, fixed. 15char